# Adding subview to another subview using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, subview, addsubview

I'm sure I am missing something stupid here, but I have mainView, subviewA, and subviewB. I am trying to add subviewB to subviewA and anchor it inside of subviewA, however it is not anchoring (just remains in top left corner. However, if I add subviewB to mainView and then anchor it, it works fine.

Example (using a custom anchoring function that I believe is self-explanatory):

```
addSubview(questionContainerView)
questionContainerView.anchor(topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: centerYAnchor, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)


// does not work
questionContainerView.addSubview(questionTextLabel)
questionTextLabel.anchor(questionContainerView.topAnchor, left: questionContainerView.leftAnchor, bottom: questionContainerView.bottomAnchor, right: questionContainerView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 25, leftConstant: 10, bottomConstant: 25, rightConstant: 10, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

// does work
addSubview(questionTextLabel)
questionTextLabel.anchor(questionContainerView.topAnchor, left: questionContainerView.leftAnchor, bottom: questionContainerView.bottomAnchor, right: questionContainerView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 25, leftConstant: 10, bottomConstant: 25, rightConstant: 10, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same code with different background color and found nothing wrong with it, maybe because of same background color, it wont be visible.

Please find the code below

```
        self.view.addSubview(questionContainerView)
    questionContainerView.anchor(top: self.view.topAnchor, left: self.view.leftAnchor, bottom: self.view.centerYAnchor, right: self.view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    questionContainerView.backgroundColor = .blue

    questionContainerView.addSubview(questionTextLabel)
    questionTextLabel.anchor(top: questionContainerView.topAnchor, left: questionContainerView.leftAnchor, bottom: questionContainerView.bottomAnchor, right: questionContainerView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 25, leftConstant: 10, bottomConstant: 25, rightConstant: 10, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    questionTextLabel.backgroundColor = .black
```

[image: please find the screenshot attached]

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that this is inside a cell, not a view controller. Not sure if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the same view to two separate parent views. Once you add it to a different view, it will be removed from the previous view. If you want the label view on both views, simply create two instances of it.

```
questionContainerView.addSubview(questionTextLabel) // first time
addSubview(questionTextLabel) // second time the questionTextLabel is removed from questionContainerView
```